# Bundler doesn't install dependencies of my gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, dependencies, bundler

I created a gem with `gemspec`:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name           = 'my_gem'
  s.version        = '0.0.1'
  s.date           = '2019-05-31'
  s.summary        = 'summary'
  s.description    = 'description'
  s.authors        = ['my name']
  s.email          = 'my@email.com'
  s.files          = Dir['{lib}/**/*.rb', 'bin/*', '*.md']
  s.require_path   = 'lib'
  s.executables    = ['some_bin']
  s.homepage       = 'https://some.homepage.com'
  s.license        = 'MIT'
  s.add_dependency 'hidapi', '= 0.1.9'
end
```

I expected, that after adding my gem to the `Gemfile`, bundler will install not only `my_gem`, but also dependencies, that is `hidapi`. However when I try to run `rails s` I get an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
bin/rails: Bootsnap::LoadPathCache::FallbackScan
(...)
kernel_require.rb:22:in `require': cannot load such file -- hidapi (LoadError)
```

In Gemfile.lock `my_gem` doesn't have any dependency. What did I miss?

## Solution

I thought that bundler uses only gemspec, but it looks it uses Gemfile of my gem. My gemfile also had all dependencies, but it should require `gemspec` directly. It should look like this:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

source 'https://rubygems.org'

gemspec
```

I don't even know if `source 'https://rubygems.org'` is necessary.

Comment: My gem is in rubygems. The version is correct. No need for update, I just set up the project.

Comment: Ok, I solved it, I will add an answer in my post.